# Where should I ask a mix of did I understand it or did I use it wrong questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I checked yesterday that [activity feed API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/activity-feed-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0), from Microsoft for Windows 10. I made all the required [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) requests and inserted the activity and I got a positive server response. However I was unable to read my inserted data nor I was able to see any changes on my Windows 10 installation.

So I'm right now sure, if this is an wrong implementation (Stack Overflow) or regarding the usage of Windows (Super User). Somehow it is a mix of both. Which site should I use?

Comment: As I told you in chat yesterday "As it stands your question is neither one thing or another, and is so lacking in any details it would be closed on either site."

Comment: "You haven't said what your program is supposed to do, or what is actually does, and why it doesn't do what you want. You have to assume we know nothing at all about your program."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (assuming you add the required debugging details) would be a programming question: you are confirming that your understanding and usage of an API is correct. Such a question would be best suited for Stack Overflow.

The usage of Windows is incidental and is only relevant in the context of what the API does, so this wouldn't really make sense for Super User.

Just in case it's not clear: the first paragraph of your question would not be nearly enough. You'd need to provide the code, any errors, etc.

Comment: Where it would be immediately closed. Saying my program doesn't work is not a good start to asking a question. There is no code, no error message, no expected behavior etc ,etc.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm assuming they aren't literally posting the first paragraph as the question; that would be obviously inadequate. That's what I was referring to with "the required debugging details." I edited my post to further clarify that.

Comment: Thank you guys for your input. On Stack Overflow I would add at least the API calls I did, so of cause without code nobody can help. I wrote this as a meta question basically because I was not sure, the real question will contain more details of cause.

Answer (score 2):

> I checked yesterday that activity feed API, from Microsoft for Windows 10. I made all the required OAuth requests and inserted the activity and I got a positive server response. However I was unable to read my inserted data nor I was able to see any changes on my Windows 10 installation.

I suspect this ought to be a classic "This is what I did" "This is what I expected" "but this is what I got" question.

Sharing a MVE snippet of what you were coding means it dosen't matter if you misunderstood it (since the reply would be - that's the expected output *but* something else might work, or it won't work). If everything looks right, then maybe look at the windows end, but I suspect this would be a better fit for SO than Super User

Comment: Thank you guys for your input. I will ask on Stack Overflow with at least the API calls I did, so it should be clear if I'm on the right path or not.